# Graalvm and Spring Boot - Cant Build Or Understand error

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Im a bit newbie with graalVm + Spring Boot and Im trying to run native image with one application but I cant build the image or understand the error.
The error log [ I cut some part of the log because of the limit on body message, tecniccaly as I understood, its just copping all the files ]:

```
            #12 70.25 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            #12 70.25 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
            #12 70.25 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            #12 70.25 [INFO] Total time:  01:07 min
            #12 70.25 [INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-26T23:32:17Z
            #12 70.25 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]
            #12 70.25 [WARNING] Plugin validation issues were detected in 1 plugin(s)
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]   Declared at location(s):
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]    * org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.1.1 (/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/3.1.1/spring-boot-dependencies-3.1.1.pom) @ line 2588
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]   Used in module(s):
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]    * com.arar.arar.api:arar-arar-api:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (pom.xml)
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]   Mojo issue(s):
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]    * Mojo surefire:test (org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin)
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]      - Parameter 'systemProperties' is deprecated: Use systemPropertyVariables instead.
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]
            #12 70.25 [WARNING] Fix reported issues by adjusting plugin configuration or by upgrading above listed plugins. If no upgrade available, please notify plugin maintainers about reported issues.
            #12 70.25 [WARNING] For more or less details, use 'maven.plugin.validation' property with one of the values (case insensitive): [BRIEF, DEFAULT, VERBOSE]
            #12 70.25 [WARNING]
            #12 70.25 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.25:compile-no-fork (build-native) on project arar-arar-api: Execution of /opt
            /graalvm/bin/native-image -cp /app/target/classes:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.9.1/gson-2.9.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/31.1-j
            re/guava-31.1-jre.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-em
            pty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.
            jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.12.0/checker-qual-3.12.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.11.0/erro
            r_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/goodforgod/gson-configur
            ation/1.4.1/gson-configuration-1.4.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/3.1.1/spring-boot-starter-web-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/reposit
            ory/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.1.1/spring-boot-starter-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.1.1/spr
            ing-boot-starter-logging-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.4.8/logback-classic-1.4.8.jar:/root/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/
            1.4.8/logback-core-1.4.8.jar:/root/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeya
            ml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/3.1.1/spring-boot-starter-json-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fast
            erxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.15.2/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.15.2/
            jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.15.2/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.2.jar:/ro
            ot/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.10/spring-web-6.0.10.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.10/spring-beans-6.0.10.jar:/root
            /.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-observation/1.11.1/micrometer-observation-1.11.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.11.1/micrometer-co
            mmons-1.11.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.10/spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.10/s
            pring-context-6.0.10.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.10/spring-expression-6.0.10.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/sp
            ring-boot-starter-undertow/3.1.1/spring-boot-starter-undertow-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-core/2.3.7.Final/undertow-core-2.3.7.Final.jar:/root/.
            m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.5.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.5.1.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-api/3.8.8.Final/xnio-api-3.8.8.Final.ja
            r:/root/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/common/wildfly-common/1.5.4.Final/wildfly-common-1.5.4.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/wildfly/client/wildfly-client-config/1.0.1.
            Final/wildfly-client-config-1.0.1.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-nio/3.8.8.Final/xnio-nio-3.8.8.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/threads/jbo
            ss-threads/3.5.0.Final/jboss-threads-3.5.0.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-servlet/2.3.7.Final/undertow-servlet-2.3.7.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository
            /jakarta/servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/6.0.0/jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/undertow/undertow-websockets-jsr/2.3.7.Final/undertow-websockets-jsr-2.
            3.7.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/jakarta/websocket/jakarta.websocket-api/2.1.0/jakarta.websocket-api-2.1.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/jakarta/websocket/jakarta.websocke
            t-client-api/2.1.0/jakarta.websocket-client-api-2.1.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/10.1.10/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.10.jar:/root/.m2/rep
            ository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.1/log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.7/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:/root/.m2/repository
            /org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.17.1/log4j-core-2.17.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.17.1/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar:/root/.m2/reposito
            ry/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/3.1.1/spring-boot-configuration-processor-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring
            -boot-devtools/3.1.1/spring-boot-devtools-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.1.1/spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/sprin   
    cut
  yaml/2.15.2/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.15.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/swagger/core/v3/swagg
            er-annotations/2.2.2/swagger-annotations-2.2.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/swagger/core/v3/swagger-models/2.2.2/swagger-models-2.2.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/webjar
            s/swagger-ui/4.14.0/swagger-ui-4.14.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.52/webjars-locator-core-0.52.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/ja
            ckson/core/jackson-core/2.15.2/jackson-core-2.15.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/github/classgraph/classgraph/4.8.149/classgraph-4.8.149.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/newr
            elic/agent/java/newrelic-api/8.0.1/newrelic-api-8.0.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/modelmapper/modelmapper/2.3.5/modelmapper-2.3.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/projectl
            ombok/lombok/1.18.28/lombok-1.18.28.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/buildtools/native-maven-plugin/0.9.25/native-maven-plugin-0.9.25.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/g
            raalvm/buildtools/junit-platform-native/0.9.25/junit-platform-native-0.9.25.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-console/1.9.3/junit-platform-cons
            ole-1.9.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-reporting/1.9.3/junit-platform-reporting-1.9.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-pl
            atform-launcher/1.9.3/junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/buildtools/utils/0.9.25/utils-0.9.25.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jac
            kson/core/jackson-databind/2.15.2/jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.15.2/jackson-annotations-2.15.2.jar:
            /root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/buildtools/graalvm-reachability-metadata/0.9.25/graalvm-reachability-metadata-0.9.25.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/nativeimage/s
            vm/22.0.0/svm-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/sdk/graal-sdk/22.0.0/graal-sdk-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/nativeimage/objectfile/22.0.0/objec
            tfile-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/nativeimage/pointsto/22.0.0/pointsto-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/compiler/compiler/22.0.0/compiler-22.
            0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/truffle/truffle-api/22.0.0/truffle-api-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/nativeimage/native-image-base/22.0.0/native-
            image-base-22.0.0.jar --no-fallback -H:Path=/app/target -H:Name=arar-arar-api -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f4153
            70a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.2.0.Final,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.apache.h
            ttpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.14,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.5.0.Final,/app/targ
            et/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/3.0.2,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f41537
            0a29427c7eaff7995747700702/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/ch.qos.logback/logback
            -classic/1.4.1,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/io.undertow/undertow-core/2.2.19.Final,/app/target/graalvm-reachabilit
            y-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/7.0.4.Final,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29
            427c7eaff7995747700702/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.15.2,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/jakarta.ser
            vlet/jakarta.servlet-api/5.0.0,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.3.4 returned non-zero result -> [Help 1]
            #12 70.25 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.25:compile-no-fork (build-native
            ) on project arar-arar-api: Execution of /opt/graalvm/bin/native-image -cp /app/target/classes:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.9.1/gson-2.9.1.jar:/r
            oot/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/31.1-jre/guava-31.1-jre.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/root/.m2/reposi
            tory/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com
            /google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.12.0/checker-qual-3.12.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/googl
            e/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.11.0/error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar:
            /root/.m2/repository/io/goodforgod/gson-configuration/1.4.1/gson-configuration-1.4.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/3.1.1/spr
            ing-boot-starter-web-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.1.1/spring-boot-starter-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springfram
            ework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/3.1.1/spring-boot-starter-logging-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.4.8/logback-classic-1.4.8.jar:/
            root/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.4.8/logback-core-1.4.8.jar:/root/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api
            -2.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/3.1.1/spring-boot-star
            ter-json-3.1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.15.2/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/
            .9.25.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.15.2/jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-an
            notations/2.15.2/jackson-annotations-2.15.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/buildtools/graalvm-reachability-metadata/0.9.25/graalvm-reachability-metadata-0.9.25.ja
            r:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/nativeimage/svm/22.0.0/svm-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/sdk/graal-sdk/22.0.0/graal-sdk-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository
            /org/graalvm/nativeimage/objectfile/22.0.0/objectfile-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/nativeimage/pointsto/22.0.0/pointsto-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/o
            rg/graalvm/compiler/compiler/22.0.0/compiler-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graalvm/truffle/truffle-api/22.0.0/truffle-api-22.0.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/graa
            lvm/nativeimage/native-image-base/22.0.0/native-image-base-22.0.0.jar --no-fallback -H:Path=/app/target -H:Name=arar-arar-api -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=/app/ta
            rget/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.2.0.Final,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6
            e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.14,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.j
            boss.logging/jboss-logging/3.5.0.Final,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/3.0.2,/app/tar
            get/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370
            a29427c7eaff7995747700702/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.4.1,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/io.undertow/undertow-c
            ore/2.2.19.Final,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/7.0.4.Final,/app/target/
            graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.15.2,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a
            6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/5.0.0,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.3.4 returned non-zero result
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:462)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:325)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
            #12 70.25     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
            #12 70.25     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
            #12 70.25     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            #12 70.25     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
            #12 70.25     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
            #12 70.25     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
            #12 70.25     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
            #12 70.25     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
            #12 70.25 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Execution of /opt/graalvm/bin/native-image -cp /app/target/classes:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/
            code/gson/gson/2.9.1/gson-2.9.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/31.1-jre/guava-31.1-jre.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/fa
            ilureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-w
            ith-guava.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.12.0/checker-qual-3.1
     ...
            f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.5.0.Final,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.glas
            sfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/3.0.2,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2,/app/target/graalvm
            -reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.4.1,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7ea
            ff7995747700702/io.undertow/undertow-core/2.2.19.Final,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.hibernate.validator/hibern
            ate-validator/7.0.4.Final,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.15.2,/app/tar
            get/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/5.0.0,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f
            415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1,/app/target/graalvm-reachability-metadata/8c8a6e82f415370a29427c7eaff7995747700702/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.3.4 returned non-zero result
            #12 70.25     at org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.AbstractNativeImageMojo.buildImage (AbstractNativeImageMojo.java:414)
            #12 70.25     at org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.NativeCompileNoForkMojo.execute (NativeCompileNoForkMojo.java:96)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:462)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:325)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:910)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
            #12 70.25     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
            #12 70.25     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
            #12 70.25     at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
            #12 70.25     at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            #12 70.25     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
            #12 70.25     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
            #12 70.25     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
            #12 70.25     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
            #12 70.25     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
            #12 70.25 [ERROR]
            #12 70.25 [ERROR]
            #12 70.25 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
            #12 70.25 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, file-static, gav, static]
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down 'file-lock' factory
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down 'rwlock-local' factory
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down 'semaphore-local' factory
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down 'noop' factory
            #12 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -c mvn -Pnative native:compile -X -Dmaven.plugin.validation=VERBOSE" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
            ------
            > [build-env 6/9] RUN mvn -Pnative native:compile -X -Dmaven.plugin.validation=VERBOSE:
            #12 70.25     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
            #12 70.25 [ERROR]
            #12 70.25 [ERROR]
            #12 70.25 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
            #12 70.25 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, file-static, gav, static]
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down 'file-lock' factory
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down 'rwlock-local' factory
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down 'semaphore-local' factory
            #12 70.25 [DEBUG] Shutting down 'noop' factory
```

My plugin on pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>

                <skipNativeTests>true</skipNativeTests>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: what command do you use to compile, it would be easier to investigate if you share a reproducer ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using native-maven-plugin on windows. It's a bug, it fixed in version 0.9.28